# setting cursor position in EditText with pixels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How can i set the cursor position in an `EditText` using pixels?

I have tried `setSelection()`, but it sets the position based on character position, not pixels.

Thanks

Comment: What would the purpose of getting the pixel value for this be?

Comment: Act i have lots of images on my application on gallary view. i can write text on any image of them. and on every image i want to write from a particular position..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `padding` for your `EditText`. You can do this in the xml file or in code. I posted both methods below, using `paddingLeft` as an example and using `100px` as an example.

---

In your xml file, set the `android:paddingLeft="100px"` on your `EditText`.

This will adjust the `TextView` inside your `EditText` to be offset by the amount of pixels specified in `android:paddingLeft="100px"`.

**OR**

In code you can do it like this:

`editText.setPadding(100, 0, 0, 0);`

Where you replace `100` with whatever amount of pixels you want offset.

Comment: thxx... but i cant set the cursor anywhere on edittext throw this.

Comment: It worked both ways with the code i used to test. Are you wanting to set the cursor position after someone has typed something in it? If so, i do not believe that is possible with pixels. You would just have to use the `setSelection` to get the cursor between certain characters.

Comment: Are you wanting to set the cursor position after someone has typed something in it?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this..

```
etmsg.setText("Updated Text From another Activity");
int position = etmsg.length();
Editable etext = etmsg.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```